# Compare two lists of strings and remove partially matching items

Tags: haskell

I have `allItems` string list.

I have `badItems` string list.

I want a **new list of items** that contains the items from `allItems` that not contains the `badItems`:

```
badsItems = ["bad1","bad2"]
allItems = ["foo good1 bar","foo bad1 bar","foo bad2 bar","foo good2 bar"]
```

The funcion above performs the first part of the operations, comparing the bad item `"bad1"` with all the elements of `allItems` and producing a new list without the items that contains `"bad1"`:

```
import Data.List

eraseStrFromList :: String -> [String] -> [String]
eraseStrFromList str list = 
  filter ( not . isInfixOf str ) list
```

The result is ok (no items that contains `"bad1"` items):

```
eraseStrFromList "bad1" allItems
["foo good1 bar","foo bad2 bar","foo good2 bar"]
```

Surely I have to perform a new recursive function that calls `eraseStrFromList` function but I don't know how to approach it.

Thanks!

Comment: you can use `foldl`. or `foldr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can make your predicate (the function by which you filter) look at a list of bad words rather than a single bad word:

```
import Data.List

eraseStrFromList :: String -> [String] -> [String]
eraseStrFromList badWords list = 
  filter ( not . hasBads ) list
  where
    hasBads str = any (\bad -> isInfixOf bad str) badWords
```

Note that I gave this predicate a new name - `hasBads`. This makes it easier to think about it. But it is also possible to put it inline:

```
filter (\str -> not $ any (\bad -> isInfixOf bad str) badWords) list
```

Comment: Fyodor, works like a charm. Now, I understand functional programming a little better. The second approach, for me, is pure poetry. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So you have written a function that filters out one bad item, an excellent starting point.

One way to solve the whole problem is to make a list of such filtering functions, one function per bad item. Then, we compose all these functions, and we're done.

We need an auxiliary function to compose a list of filtering functions. As suggested by Will Ness, we can use `foldr`:

```
import Data.List

badItems  =  ["bad1","bad2"]
allItems  =  ["foo good1 bar","foo bad1 bar","foo bad2 bar","foo good2 bar"]

eraseStrFromList :: String -> [String] -> [String]
eraseStrFromList str list = filter  (not . (isInfixOf str))  list

composeFilters ::  [ ([String] -> [String]) ]  ->  ([String] -> [String])
composeFilters filterList = foldr (.) id filterList
```

The way we've just defined `composeFilters` is very similar to the definition of `sum xs` as `foldr (+) 0 xs`.

The list of filtering functions is simply `map eraseStrFromList badItems`, thanks to the magic of [currying](https://wiki.haskell.org/Currying).

So the total filtering function can be written like this:

```
mainFilter :: [String] -> [String] -> [String]
mainFilter bads list = (composeFilters $ map eraseStrFromList bads) $ list
```

Indeed, checking under ghci:

```
 λ> 
 λ> mainFilter badItems allItems
["foo good1 bar","foo good2 bar"]
 λ>
```

### Alternative solution:

Instead of a main filtering function, we can use a main *predicate* function, that returns True only if no bad item is found herein.

For this, we can use the `or` function, which takes a list of boolean values and returns True iff at least one of the input values is True.

Like this:

```
mainFilter2 :: [String] -> [String] -> [String]
mainFilter2 bads strList =
    let  mainPred str = not $ or (map  (\bad -> isInfixOf bad str)  bads)
    in   filter mainPred strList
```

Comment: Thanks for the briefing jpmarinier. It has been very helpful for me.